# Exponential generating function for the Bell numbers

Tags: number-theory, bell-numbers

I've recently come across the Bell numbers, defined as:

\begin{equation*}
B_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}B_{k}.
\end{equation*}
The exponential generating function of the Bell numbers is known to be:
\begin{equation*}
B(x) = e^{e^{x}-1}.
\end{equation*}

If I understand this correctly, the x-th Bell number can calso be computed using this generating function, yet when, for example, inserting the value 2 as input, the output is of course not 2; yet $B_{2} = 2$. What exactly does this function imply then---how is this related to Bell numbers?

I realize this might be a very basic question, if there is any relevant literature for this topic I would be grateful.

Comment: One source of information on generating functions is the book *generatingfunctionology* by Wilf. https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Exponential generating function $B(x)$" means when you expand it in a power series
$$
e^{e^x-1} = 1+x+{x}^{2}+{\frac {5}{6}}{x}^{3}+{\frac {5}{8}}{x}^{4}+{\frac {13}{
30}}{x}^{5}+O \left( {x}^{6} \right) 
$$
then the coefficient of $x^k$ is $B_k/k!$.  So if (your example) you want $B_2$, you look at the coefficient of $x^2$, which is $1$, so that $B_2/2!=1$ and therefore $B_2=2! = 2$.

Another example.  The coefficient of $x^5$ is $13/30$, so $B_5/5! = 13/30$, from which we get $B_5 = (13/30) 5! = 52$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand clearly now.